# regarding visual slam

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement any one of the visual slam menthods in the robot? Is there any successful visual slam packages in ROS? Or an other open sources for implementing visual slam?

Also, I have noticed one of the open source mrpt. And they have packages in ROS. But, I can not find any proper tutorials for that?

So, Do you know any open source for visual slam or any tutorials for mrpt_ros or mrpt?

Thanks for the reply in advance..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38271/regarding-visual-slam/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are currently a few options for doing Visual SLAM using ROS (in no particular order):

- [viso2_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros) is a ROS wrapper for a visual    odometry package developed at KIT, some people had good results with this. Also can be combined with [cyphy_vis_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cyphy_vis_slam) for a full blown SLAM system including graph optimization. The latter is currently in ongoing development from what I understand.
- [RGB-D SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) performs SLAM using a handheld Kinect and also is used by quite a few people with success.
- [ethzasl_ptam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_ptam) is an adapted version of the original [PTAM](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Egk/PTAM/) for the use with ROS and on computationally constrained quadrotor MAVs. I already used this on a simulated quadrotor in gazebo with good success.
- [vslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam) for ROS is a experimental VSLAM implementation that hasn't received many updates lately, so not sure if it will work with current ROS versions.

There are also promising approaches like [ScaViSLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ScaViSLAM) or the [PCL Kinect Fusion clone](http://pointclouds.org/news/kinectfusion-open-source.html), but these do not work with ROS out of the box AFAIK.

As for your question about Kalman Filter based vision based SLAM: Here's a [pretty good paper](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eajd/Publications/strasdat_etal_ivc2012.pdf) about why (Kalman) filtering isn't necessarily the best option.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-07-11**:
Just a note: viso2_ros does not do SLAM but visual odometry only. There is no data associacion or loop closing. However, it can be used as motion prediction for various VSLAM systems such as RGBDSLAM.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-07-11**:
http://openslam.org/ is also a great resource on open source SLAM algorithms. Some of them have wrappers for ROS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RGBD SLAM is a visual SLAM technique. You can use stereo camera as the sensor.
Have a look at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1